# On how can "jedes" be translated in this context

Tags: grammar

> Jedes Gesicht ist vom Maler ganz genau gemalt worden.

This should mean, **Every face [probably portrait?] has been painted by the painter quite well.**

However, [LEO](http://dict.leo.org/?lang=de&lp=ende#/search=jedes&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on) says *jedes* means *any*. But *Any face...* doesn't seem to make as good a sense as *Every face... does*.

Which way is it then?

Comment: If you look further down you can also find every as a translation (in the Präposition section). Leo is a nice source but the one big problem is that the first translation is rarely the most common one. So if you're a beginner I suggest staying away from Leo and use Pons instead since they provide context and examples

Comment: Yes, I'm still a beginner. Very much still hopelessly so... Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: `Quite well` würde ich mit `recht gut` übersetzen, `ganz genau` mit `absolute precisely`.

Comment: For all faces f, the following holds: f has been painted .... just kidding ....

Comment: But srsly, why not: `All faces have been painted ...`

Answer (score 5):

"Every" would be the correct translation in this case. As already pointed out by Emanuel, this translation is included in the list on LEO.

Also just to nitpick a little, in this sentence a more correct translation for "genau" would be "precisely" or "finely".

Answer (score 4):

*Each* would technically be closer.

*Every* means *they, all, together*: *Alle Gesichter sind vom Maler .*

*Each* means *every single one*: *Jedes Gesicht is vom Maler .*